# sql server agent not starting after system reboot

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of jobs that run everyday. Once the jobs are done the system reboots. Few days ago I have noticed that the server agent is not starting though it is set to automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server service doesn't start anymore automatically if I make a Windows restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797295/sql-server-service-doesnt-start-anymore-automatically-if-i-make-a-windows-resta)

Answer (score 0):

go to services stop that service restart your system again start the service make as automatic and then again reboot.

Comment: that's i know as u explained in your question so just do it as above